# Running MPI directly from the Python script, without mpiexec call

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I would like to run tje MPI from the Python script without calling for example:
`mpiexec -n 2 python my)script.py`
from the console.

So I would like to make all the mpi initialization from the Python itself and run the script normally. Is that possible?

The reason for that is just regular run from PyCharm environment, which has no mpi support.

Comment: you can `python my_script.py` (this is known as singleton mode), but you will run only one MPI task (instead of two with `mpiexec -n 2 ...`)

Comment: That trick I know, but when I want to run pararel without mpi - that's tricky :)

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel and use a simple wrapper.

Comment: So "I will never pass the gateless gate if I will think too much" right? :p Thank you master :) Well I use simple mpiexec, but I wonder if anybody else "reinvented" this wheel?

Comment: `mpiexec` is implementation specific (read MPICH and Open MPI do not inter-operate). An option is to start `my_script.py` in singleton mode, and then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` the second task (and take care of the "details'). Or have the Python (singleton mode) `MPI_Comm_spawn()` the 2 MPI tasks (and take care of the "details" too.

Comment: Yes, and that seems to be the answer, but I'm no so much familiar with MPI (and I use MPI wrapper from NEURON simulator by the way) so if you may provide any more detailed answer (not in the comment) I would be very glad. But if not, it works well from the console, but I haven't figured out how to debug it in PyCharm.